# Cypress get elements inside each loop

Tags: jquery, cypress, e2e-testing

I have a table , the first column cell contains a div and image .
I need to click on div.
I also need to perform some test on third column.
So i gave the selector till td and didn't include div.

```
cy.get("f-shared-table cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport mat-table tr.mat-row td:nth-child(1)").each(($el, index, $list) => {
            if(index === 10) {
                // how to get the div to click it
            }
        })
```

I know i can achieve it using

```
cy.get("fcsky-shared-table cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport mat-table tr.mat-row td:nth-child(1) div").eq(10).click()
```

I was wondering if there is any way where i can get the elements inside each

```
cy.get("f-shared-table cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport mat-table tr.mat-row td:nth-child(1)").each(($el, index, $list) => {
            if(index === 10) {
                cy.wrap($el).get("div").click() // not working
                cy.wrap($el).children("div").click() // not working
            }
        })
```

Comment: I think you were close and it will work if you replace `cy.wrap($el).get('div')` to `cy.wrap($el).find('div')`

Comment: Given we don't have more information, Leomelzer is probably right. `.get()` queries from the root level DOM element. `.find()` will query from the passed in element.

Comment: If `cy.wrap($el).children("div")` does not work probably `cy.wrap($el).find("div")` will not work either.. What is the HTML inside the '<td>'?

Comment: Also, since you have `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` the Cypress `.each()` command will not work. You need a command to scroll the table in order to access all the rows.

Comment: The first td contains div and img. Let me try .find() . I was just looking for this part if there is a way where I can go inside each loop and start Cy.get again. Mostly find will resolve

Comment: @FayFulbright I am new in testing, so will search on how to scroll for cdk

Answer (score 3):

You may find it easier to use the row as index, and within the 11th row find the `<div>`, something like:

```js
cy.get('f-shared-table cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport mat-table tr.mat-row')
  .each(($tr, index) => {
    if (index === 10) {
      cy.wrap($tr).within(() => {
        // the following command is limited to eleventh row
        cy.get('td').first().find('div').click() 
      })        
    }
  })
```

Comment: Let me read about .within() , looking at the answer I am assuming it allows to start the locator after the parent locator and we don't have to write all of the previous one again